# datagridview column name not found

Tags: datagridview

I am programming in VB.NET and have a `datagridview` that is automatically populated from a database.

When I use code such as `dgvPurchases.Rows(dgvPurchases.SelectedRows(i).Index).Cells("Head").Value` I receive an error column name "Head" not found.

This is the column name in my datatable and when I do an `Edit Columns`, it shows "Head" as the `DataPropertyName`.   One answer on the web was to rename the column, but I can find out how to rename the Header, but not the column.

When I go to `Purchases.Designer.vb`, I find       `Me.HeadDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()`.

On columns added to the database after I originally designed the form, they show `Me.CkOff = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()` and `dgvPurchases.Rows(dgvPurchases.SelectedRows(i).Index).Cells("CkOff").Value`returns a value.

I know I can use the column number; however, if I change the datatable, correcting the code becomes problematic.   Using data column names is much preferable

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by going to `FORMNAME.Designer.vb`and changing

`'HeadDataGridViewTextBoxColumn ' Me.Head.DataPropertyName = "Head" Me.Head.HeaderText = "Head" Me.Head.Name = "HeadDataGridViewTextBoxColumn" Me.Head.Width = 40`

to

`'HeadDataGridViewTextBoxColumn ' Me.Head.DataPropertyName = "Head" Me.Head.HeaderText = "Head" Me.Head.Name = "Head" Me.Head.Width = 40`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem that could be solved in a similar manner.
After a little more digging, I found that the problem was caused when I set the DataSource of the DataGridView to Nothing in an attempt to clear it.

When I did a datatable.clear on the underlying data table that I was using as a datasource instead, the issue went away.